# How can I stop VS2010 from lauching the wcf host when it's not needed?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I imported a vs2008 solution containing a class library with a wcf service defined in it. The solution also contains a console project which holds the hosting app for the service. The console app is set as the startup project. When I hit Debug, the console app tries to open the service host, but vs2010 also launches the generic WcfHost. This causes console app to crash.

How do I stop the WcfHost from launching and competing with the console app that hosts the services too?

or should I stop the console app from hosting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly sure about VS2010, but in VS2008, right-click the class library project w/ the WCF service in the Solution Explorer and select **Properties**.  You should see a **WCF Options** tab.  That tab has a checkbox that, to the best of my recollection, is checked by default.  I have long since unchecked it, but it controls the startup of the WcfHost.  Again, I'm not sure about VS2010, but I would look for a project property setting that controls this.